# Hyper-V Host Compute Service doesn't start Win 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

Hyper-V Host Compute Service doesn't start on Win 10.
Here is the error message I get when try running service manually.
[image]

Service worked until recently. CPU virtualization setup in BIOS is ON.
I increased the ServicesPipeTimeout to 1.5 minutes that should be long enough. It fails to start anyway.

No configuration changes where made on PC by my intentionally. However PC is in a domain and modification could be made remotely by IT stuff.

Here is the whole list of Hyper-V related services installed. I don't have a clue why are they so many.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps on Win 10 from [this link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4821#issuecomment-537061525):

```
Open "Window Security"
Open "App & Browser control"
Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
Switch to "Program settings" tab
Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
Click "Edit"
Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"
```

It works for me.